# Integrate $\int{\frac{\sin(2x)+\cos(2x)}{(\sin(2x)-\cos(2x))^{5/2}}}\,\mathrm dx$.

Tags: calculus, integration

> Integrate $$\int{\frac{\sin(2x)+\cos(2x)}{(\sin(2x)-\cos(2x))^{5/2}}}\,\mathrm
>  dx.$$

How do I integrate such an integral?

u-substitution, no idea

by parts, no idea

this is very confusing!  please help!

Comment: You posted an erlier problem that was structurally almost the same as this one. It is important to use MSE answers to solve problems on  your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

With inside functions, in this case $(\sin 2x-\cos 2x)$, a $u$-substitution is a great place to start.

Comment: Ok, so I should make u=sin2x-cos2x, then du=2cos2x+2sin2x=2(cos2x+sin2x)

Comment: Oh that's right, thanks soo much!

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do when facing sums of trigonometric functions is to use the sum identities:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\sin (a + b) &= \sin a \cos b + \cos a \sin b \\
\cos (a + b) &= \cos a \cos b - \sin a \sin b
\end{eqnarray}
$$

In the expressions you have, sines and cosines have the same coefficient (essentially).  So, use $\sin \pi/4 = \cos \pi/4 = 1/\sqrt2$.

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\sin 2x + \cos{2x}&= \sqrt2 \sin 2x \cos \pi/4 + \sqrt2 \cos2x \sin \pi/4\\
&=\sqrt2 \sin(2x + \pi/4)\\
\cos 2x - \sin{2x}&= \sqrt2 \cos 2x \cos \pi/4 - \sqrt2 \sin 2x \sin \pi/4\\
&= \sqrt2 \cos(2x + \pi/4)
\end{eqnarray}
$$

The integral becomes:

$$
\int{\frac{\sqrt2\sin(2x + \pi/4)}{(-\sqrt2\cos(2x + \pi/4))^{5/2}}}\
 dx
$$

Substitute $u = 2x + \pi/4$ and pull out the factors of $\sqrt2$ to get:

$$
\frac14 \int{\frac{\sin u}{(-\cos u)^{5/2}}}\
 du
$$

Let $v = -\cos u$:

$$
-\frac16 \int{\frac{dv}{v^{5/2}}}\
 du = -\frac16 v^{-\frac32} + C
$$

Now, substitute back for $u$, and then for $x$.